# Why is it necessary to pass rootIdx as an address?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, inorder

This is a leetcode problem "Construct Binary Tree from Preorder and Inorder Traversal" and in this solution I am wondering why do we have pass "int rootIdx = 0;" as an address, and why my code fails if I just pass it by value.

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {
        int rootIdx = 0;
        return build(preorder, inorder, rootIdx, 0, inorder.size()-1);
    }
    
    TreeNode* build(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder, int& rootIdx, int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) return NULL;
        int pivot = left;  // find the root from inorder
        while(inorder[pivot] != preorder[rootIdx]) pivot++;
        
        rootIdx++;
        TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode(inorder[pivot]);
        newNode->left = build(preorder, inorder, rootIdx, left, pivot-1);
        newNode->right = build(preorder, inorder, rootIdx, pivot+1, right);
        return newNode;
    }
};
```

Thank You already

Comment: Because `rootIdx` is a unique identifier for a root. Every time you are building the left-hand side tree, you are creating new subtrees and hence, "consuming" the valid `rootIdx`. You cannot know beforehand how large will be the left-hand side tree, so `rootIdx` should be updated accordingly to be used as base for when you are building the right-hand side tree. Try running this algorithm by-hand with pen and paper starting with very elementary trees to see the effect of modifying such a "global" variable.

Comment: But root index is nothing but some integer value ranging from 0 to size -1, so I didn't quite get you why we are doing that because all we want from root node is to point to our pivot which any valid integer in the range will do